# Left aligning items in a column grid with each other

Tags: html, css

Have a section `id="contact"` where I am trying to put a heading and a brief one sentence description underneath in one column and an email submit form with a submit button under the input field in the right column. I want the email input element to reach across the entirety of the right column and have the button left aligned to it's edge underneath it. I have a sketch to show what I am looking for attached.

So far this section does everything I want it to do right now, however the top elements under the bottom elements are not left edge aligning although the class items `.latest-from-here .input-email` (nested inside the parent section #contact) are `justify-self:start; align-self: center;`.

https://codepen.io/holmedw/pen/KrvJEb

Sketch:

[image: sketch]

```
 #contact {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    justify-items: left;
    grid-column-gap: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    height: 480px;
    align-items:center;
}

.latest-from-here .input-email {
    position:relative;
    z-index: -1;
    justify-self:start;
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you write your HTML code also?

Comment: Here's the link https://codepen.io/holmedw/pen/KrvJEb

Answer (score 0):

if you removed justify-items: left; in #contact and added width:100% to your input field that will solve the problem.

```css
*{
box-sizing:border-box
}
#contact {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    height: 480px;
    align-items:center;
}

.latest-from-here .input-email {
    position:relative;
    z-index: -1;
    justify-self:start;
    align-self: center;
}

.email{
width:100%

}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
              <div class="latest-from-here">
                <h2>Get the latest from Aer</h2>
                <p>Don't miss out on new arrivals, offers and events.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="input-email">
                <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
                  <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="email" required/>
                  <div></div>
                  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-submit"></input>                
              </form> 
              </div>
            </section>
```